# jsPDF & html2canvas not writing image to pdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

Using jspdf and html2canvas to take a snapshot of a users chosen configuration on a table configurator (choose top/side/laminate colors).  Its achieved by changing the source of each image using transparent png.

I'm having issues inserting the image into the pdf.  I can append it to the document with no issues and write text and other images to the pdf without issue.  I fear my image is way too large.  The generated base64 output is massive.

I have it writing to the console:

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt','a4',true);
doc.setFontSize(16);
doc.setTextColor(80, 77, 78);
doc.text(15, 2, 'should be an image under here'); 
html2canvas($("#prod"), {
    useCORS : true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
       var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

       doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 0, 34, 37);
        console.log(imgData);
        $('#prod').append(canvas);
    }
});
doc.save('Spec_Sheet.pdf');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x3x0e6ws/51/

All images are coming from local server.  I have a min-height on each of the elements, I even tried throwing text in the div to force a height.

How can I remedy this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, greatly appreciate the jsfiddle.
Secondly, you were very close... just move your doc.save inside your html2canvas callback.

To explain why:

When you call html2canvas, this is an "asynchronous" call. That's why the second argument of the function is a "callback". The code continues on with the next line (in your case, `doc.save`) before it actually finished rendering or adding the `canvas` element!  At some point later, the code `html2canvas` code returns to the callback when the canvas rendering is finished, and adds the image to your (already saved) pdf...!

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt','a4',true);
doc.setFontSize(16);
doc.setTextColor(80, 77, 78);
doc.text(15, 2, 'should be an image under here'); 
html2canvas($("#prod"), {
    useCORS : true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
       var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

       doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 0, 34, 37);
       console.log(imgData);
       $('#prod').append(canvas);
       doc.save('Spec_Sheet.pdf');
    }
});
```

Comment: YES!  Thank you.  Great answer and explanation.